# yii createUrl rule to return url with subdomain

Tags: php, url-rewriting, yii, routes

Suppose my yii site base domain is `http://ii.local`.

All controller actions can show on on base domain except
I need `http://events.ii.local` to process all actions of controller `event`

With the call `$this->createUrl('/event/index',array('code' => 'guruevent'))`
I need the url generated as `http://events.ii.local/guruevent`

With the call `$this->createUrl('/site/login')`
I need the url generated as `http://ii.local/site/login`.

```
'urlManager'=>array(
    'urlFormat'=>'path',
            'showScriptName'=>false,                             
            'caseSensitive'=>false,
        'rules'=>array(                                                                                     
                'http://events.ii.local/<code:\w+>'
                    => '<controller:event>/<action:index>', 
                'http://events.ii.local/<code:\w+>/<action:\w+>'
                    => '<controller:event>/<action>/<code>',
                '<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>'
                    => '<controller>/<action>',
            ),
     ),
```

Urls for event subdomain are getting generated using `/event/index?code=guruevent` and not using events.ii.local subdomain.

Single domain routing is working fine but I need to use few subdomains for few controllers and modules. I also was trying to set request->baseUrl but as soon as I set it to `http://ii.local/` all routing stops and the same homepage opens for all urls.

Please suggest the fix.

Answer (score 1):

Swap your first and second rules. The rules are processed in order, and the first to match is used. The UrlManager does not look for best matches, but rather goes first come first serve.

Since

```
$this->createUrl('/event/index',array('code' => 'guruevent'))
```

matches the pattern provided by the first rule, it will use that rule, regardless of the 'extra' data of the `code` being present.

A good rule of thumb is to always put the most specific rules first, to make sure they match, and then finish up with general rules to catch any that fail the specifics.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a custom function to create your URLs. For example `url($route, $params=array())`. You'd use `Yii::app()->createUrl()` inside and depending on `$route` would prepend it with your other hostname. Then in your project always use this function to create URLs.

If you feel confident you can also enhance your implementation and add more arguments to that function like `$schema=''` or `$absolute=false`. This way you could use this function for all kind of URL creation you will ever need in your project.

An alternative would be to write your custom `urlManager` component which extends from `CUrlManager` and then override `createUrl()`. There you could do the same as suggested above: Inspect the `$route` and create the apropriate URL.